# Tailwind classes doesn't work in Vue 3 project

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, vite

I'm having a problem where I can't make my Tailwind classes show in my project. I tried following all the open threads regarding this question but couldn't find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

---

#### My Files and Folders:

tailwind.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./src/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

main.js:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './assets/main.css'
import './tailwind.css'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

tailwind.css:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

App.vue:

```html
<script setup>

</script>

<template>
    <div class="text-5xl text-red-500 bg-slate-600 p-32 m-4">
      test
    </div>
</template>
```

Project Tree:

```
Project
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┣ assets
 ┃ ┃ ┗ main.css
 ┃ ┣ components
 ┃ ┣ App.vue
 ┃ ┣ main.js
 ┃ ┗ tailwind.css
 ┣ index.html
 ┣ package-lock.json
 ┣ package.json
 ┣ tailwind.config.js
 ┗ vite.config.js
```

Comment: Most likely you just need to add `postcss.config.js` file and include Tailwind in it

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka, This was it, thank you very much! You're welcome to add your comment as the answer, and I'll happily mark it as accepted :)